# How to get WKHTMLTOPDF working in flask on Heroku l?

Tags: python, heroku, wkhtmltopdf

I have created an app with Flask which takes some user inputs, calculates them, and then generates the pdf out of that data.

I have followed this and getting the same error: [How to get WKHTMLTOPDF working on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54707110/how-to-get-wkhtmltopdf-working-on-heroku)

Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/download')
def download():
    credit_hours = aaa['Credit Hours']
    rendered = render_template("report2.html", credit_hours=credit_hours)
    def _get_pdfkit_config():
     if platform.system() == 'Windows':
         return pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=os.environ.get('WKHTMLTOPDF_BINARY', 'C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe'))
     else:
         WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD = subprocess.Popen(['which', os.environ.get('WKHTMLTOPDF_BINARY', 'wkhtmltopdf')], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip()
         return pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD)
         
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(rendered, False, configuration=_get_pdfkit_config())
    response = make_response(pdf)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = f'inline; filename={ag_number} GPA Report.pdf'
    
    return response
```

Requirements.txt:

```
git+git://github.com/johnfraney/wkhtmltopdf-pack.git
pdfkit==0.6.1
```

Error, I am getting is "Internal Server Error" on Heroku.

The above code is working perfectly on my local machine. But when I deploy it to heroku I get

> Internal Server Error
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.