# how to run wkhtmltopdf on heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I want to run `wkhtmltopdf` on heroku, but not able to do so. I am trying to run the `wkhtmltopdf.exe` and generate `pdf`, but it shows permission denied.

**My folder Structure**

```
15-07-2020  18:06    <DIR>          .
15-07-2020  18:06    <DIR>          ..
15-07-2020  16:40    <DIR>          .idea
15-07-2020  17:33               978 app.py
15-07-2020  17:00                21 Procfile
15-07-2020  17:01               134 requirements.txt
15-07-2020  17:01                12 runtime.txt
15-07-2020  16:34    <DIR>          static
15-07-2020  18:14    <DIR>          templates
15-07-2020  16:33    <DIR>          venv
15-07-2020  17:33    <DIR>          wkhtmltopdf
15-07-2020  18:02    <DIR>          __pycache__
               4 File(s)          1,145 bytes
               8 Dir(s)  49,877,135,360 bytes free
```

**My app.py file**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, make_response

import pdfkit
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf="./wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe")
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/memo', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def memo():

    if request.method == 'POST':

        name = request.form.get('name')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        number = request.form.get('number')

        res = render_template('memo.html', name=name, email=email, number=number)
        responsestring = pdfkit.from_string(res, False, configuration=config)
        response = make_response(responsestring)
        response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
        response.headers['Content-disposition'] = 'inline;filename=test.pdf'
        return response

    else:
        return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: IS the problem solved?

Comment: nope the problem is not solved yet

Comment: Have you seen my answer and looked at the solutions from the link i mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

If it's simply a `permission denied` error, then that simply means that the `file` doesn't have the required privilege to perform the operation.

You can try to `SSH` to the Heroku server and add an executable right to the file, like so

```
sudo chmod a+x /path/to/file/FILENAME
```

You should also see the related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45164487/6505847) that may fix this with a buildpack.